# Same function is invoking for 2 buttons in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

This is my component `add-customer.component.html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="addCusForm">
    <div id="login-container">

        <h2 class="add-title">Customer Details</h2>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstname" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.firstname.hasError('required')">
                Please enter first name
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.firstname.hasError('pattern')">
                Please enter valid first name
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastname" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.lastname.hasError('required')">
                Please enter last name
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.lastname.hasError('pattern')">
                Please enter valid last name
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Email address" formControlName="email" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.email.hasError('required')">
                Please enter email id
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.email.hasError('email')">
                Please enter valid email id
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div>
            <button mat-raised-button class="Login-btn">Cancel</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onaddCus()" class="Login-btn">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I have used two buttons as shown in above code

```html
 <button mat-raised-button  class="Login-btn" >Cancel</button>
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onaddCus()" class="Login-btn" >Save</button>
```

My issue is that, I have used `(click)="onaddCus()"`  for **SAVE** button to show error message if  the user clicks **SAVE** button without filling the required input fields.But here i have not using that function `(click)="onaddCus()"` for **Cancel** button,But its still showing the error messages and if i placed that**Cancel** button outside the form it's working fine.But i want two buttons within the form only.

Below is the ts`add-customer.component.ts` file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ValidatorUtil } from '../shared/validator.util';

@Component({
    selector: 'ylb-add-customer',
    templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css']
})

export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

    addCusForm: FormGroup;
    hide = true; //password hiding

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
            'firstname': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+")]],
            'lastname': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+")]],
            'email': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            'password': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
            'confirmPassword': [null, [Validators.required, ValidatorUtil.matchWithValidator('password')]]
        });
    }

    onaddCus() {
        this._markAsDirty(this.addCusForm);
    }

    private _markAsDirty(group: FormGroup) {
        group.markAsDirty();
        for (let i in group.controls) {
            group.controls[i].markAsDirty();
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a **`button`** is of type **submit** and since you are using them inside **`<form>`**, the default behavior is to submit. Make the following changes to your template:

- Add **`(ngSubmit)="onaddCus()`** on your form
- Add **`type="button"`** on your cancel button
- Add **`type="submit"`** on your save button

---

```
<form [formGroup]="addCusForm" (ngSubmit)="onaddCus()">
  <div id="login-container">

    <!-- YOUR OTHER CODE -->

    <div>
      <button type="button" 
              mat-raised-button class="Login-btn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" 
              mat-raised-button color="primary" class="Login-btn">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```